# IP Program, setting an object to default value

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment and am running into an issue. I am trying to figure out how to get PC3 object to display the default values if the information passed to the object is invalid (an invalid IP address). As it is, the display is just showing IP: null and I need to get it to instead call the `setDefault()` method and display that.

I'm sorry for the long bit of code here but I want you to see what is going on.
Thank you so much for any help!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class IPAddress 
{           
   private String IPAddress;
   private String subnetMask;
   private int intParts[];
   private String retString;


   IPAddress(){  //sets default IP address in 169.254.X.Y, where X and Y are values between 0 and 255
      setDefault();   

   }

   IPAddress(String ip, String sm){
      setIPAddress(ip);
      setSubnetMask(sm); 
   }

   public void setDefault(){
      String temp="169.254.";
      int octet3=randVal();
      int octet4=randVal();
      while((octet3==0 && octet4==0) || (octet3==255 && octet4==255)){  //cannot have 169.254.0.0 as it is a network address
         octet4=randVal();                                              //cannot have69.254.255.255 as it is a broadcast address
      }

      temp=temp+octet3+"."+octet4;

      setIPAddress(temp);

      setSubnetMask("255.255.0.0");

   }

   public void setIPAddress(String ip){
      if(isValidIPAddress(ip)){
         IPAddress=ip;
      }
      else{
         System.out.println("Invalid IP Address:  "+ip);
      } 
   }

   public void setSubnetMask(String sm){
      if(isValidSubnetMask(sm)){
         subnetMask=sm;
      }
      else{
         System.out.println("Invalid Subnet Mask:  "+sm);
      } 
   }

   public int randVal(){
        //value between 0 and 255
      Random rnd1=new Random();

        int x=(int)(rnd1.nextDouble()*255);

        return x;
    }

    public String tellCase(){

     //String retString = "";
      if ((intParts[0] > 0) && (intParts[0] <= 128))
         retString = "A";
      else if ((intParts[0] >= 127) && (intParts[0] <= 191))
         retString = "B";
      else if ((intParts[0] >=192) && (intParts[0] <= 223))
         retString = "C";
      else if ((intParts[0] >= 224) && (intParts[0] <= 239))
         retString = "D"; 

     return retString;
    }

   public boolean checkValidIPClass (String x){
    //System.out.println(retString);  checks to make sure the string made it to the method
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         if (retString == "A"){
            if ((intParts[1] == 0) && (intParts [2] == 0) && (intParts [3] == 0))
               return false;
            if ((intParts[1] == 255) && (intParts [2] == 255) && (intParts [3] == 255))
               return false;
         }
         if (retString == "B"){
            if ((intParts [2] == 0) && (intParts [3] == 0))
               return false;
            if ((intParts [2] == 255) && (intParts [3] == 255))
               return false;

         }
         if (retString == "C"){
            if (intParts [3] == 0)
               return false;
            if (intParts [3] == 255)
               return false;
         }
   }
   return true;
}



   public boolean isValidIPAddress(String ip){ /*YOU NEED TO FILL IN THE METHOD*/

      //check to verify only 3 dots, the values in each octet are between 0 and 255 and is an IP address which can be assigned 
      //Class a 1st octet 1-127 and the rest cannot be 0's or 255's
      //Class b 1st octet 128-191 second 0-255 and last two cannot be all 0's or 255's

       try {
        if (ip == null || ip.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        String[] parts = ip.split( "\\." );
        if ( parts.length != 4 ) {
            return false;
        }

        intParts = new int[4];

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt( parts[j] );
            if ( (i < 0) || (i > 255) ) {
                return false;
            }

            intParts[j] = i;

        } //ends for loop for storing values into int array

        if(ip.endsWith(".")) {
                return false;
        }

        checkValidIPClass(tellCase());


        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }

 }

   public boolean isValidSubnetMask(String sm){  /*YOU NEED TO FILL IN THE METHOD*/

      //only checks for default subnet masks (either 255.0.0.0 or 255.255.0.0 or 255.255.255.0).
       try {
        if (sm == null || sm.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        String[] parts = sm.split( "\\." );
        if ( parts.length != 4 ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ((sm != "255.0.0.0") && (sm != "255.255.0.0") && (sm != "255.255.255.0")) {
            return false;
        }        

        if(sm.endsWith(".")) {
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
}

   public int stringToInt(String v){
      boolean answer=true;
      int returnVal=-1; 

      for(int i=0; i<v.length(); i++){  //verify all characters in v are digits
         if(!Character.isDigit(v.charAt(i))){  //as soon as 1 non-digit is found, end the loop as we know v is not a number
            answer=false;
            i=v.length()+1;
         }
      }

      if(answer){ //if v is a number, then change it to its number
         returnVal=Integer.parseInt(v);
      }
      return returnVal;  //if this is -1, then v is not a number.  otherwise, v is a number
   }

   public String getIPAddress(){
      return IPAddress;
   }

   public String getSubnetMask(){
      return subnetMask;
   }

   public String toString(){
      String returnString="IP Address:  "+IPAddress+"\n";
      returnString+="Subnet Mask:  "+subnetMask+"\n";

      return returnString;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)

   {  
      //sample creation of objects of the class
      IPAddress PC1=new IPAddress();  //uses default constructor
      IPAddress PC2=new IPAddress("165.0.0.0", "255.255.0.0");  //uses alternate constructor (overloaded)
      IPAddress PC3=new IPAddress("122..15.12.1", "255.0.0.0");   //uses alternate constructor (overloaded) - should cause errors messages to appear.

      //sample output from creation of objects of the class
      System.out.println(PC1);
      System.out.println(PC2);
      System.out.println(PC3);  //should end up printing something in 169.254.X.Y range once you have created the check methods.

      System.out.println(PC1.stringToInt("110"));  //way of testing to see how individual methods work       
      System.out.println(PC1.stringToInt("a"));  //prints -1 beacause a is not a number
      System.out.println(PC1.stringToInt("110d"));  //prints -1 because d isn't a digit
      System.out.println(PC1.stringToInt("13e5"));  //prints -1 because e isn't a digit


   }  

}  //end class
```

Answer (score 1):

So call `setDefault()` instead of

```
System.out.println("Invalid IP Address:  "+ip);
```

inside your `setIPAddress` method.

Also your setDefault has a bug,
in the while loop you regenerate only the octe4 value not octed3, so if the octed3 is not valid it will never terminate.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Any idea why my validation method isn't work? If I pass in the IP of `121.0.0.0` it should display as invalid but it's still showing valid!? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, inside isValidIPAddress you call checkValidIPClass(tellCase()); but then you always return true regardless of its result, also you don't pass the ip to your checkValid... method;


        return true;

Comment: I was under impression that the if statements would catch the problem and return false. I'm sorry I am still new at all of this. So the return true statement at the bottom is causing that? If so, what do I do to correct it? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: simply return checkValidIPClass(..); or if (checkValidIPClass()) {do some more checking} else return false

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but do I return exactly that? I get the error `IPAddress.java:108: error: illegal '.'
   return checkValidIPClass(..);
                             ^
IPAddress.java:108: error: ';' expected
   return checkValidIPClass(..);
`

Comment: It does. Add return in front of the function you are calling now. Replace the .. with calling parameters

Comment: It's not working. I call checkValidIPClass using the param tellClass, I can use print statements and see that the information is making it to the methods, but my return is still not working. I have tried my original return true, `return checkValidIPClass(tellCase);` and `return checkValidIPClass();` what am I missing here?

Comment: boolean tmp = checkValid...; System.out.println(tmp); return tmp; and see what the checkValid actually return. I am not going to debug the whole code for you. You were not returning the checkValid... method value so it could not work, maybe the checkValid.. has also a bug. I found you already 3, I believe it is enough.